# Mysql Index is not being used correctly

Tags: mysql, indexing

I got a strange problem with a simple MySQL index.

I got the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `import` (
  `import_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `import_title` text,
  `import_url` text,
  `import_description` text,
  `import_completed` enum('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
  `import_user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `import_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`import_id`),
  KEY `import_added` (`import_added`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In that table are a few thousand rows and I want to get the first 100 with the following Select Clause:

```
SELECT 
  import_id, 
  import_title, 
  import_url, 
  import_description, 
  import_user, 
  import_added 
FROM import 
WHERE import_completed = 'n' 
ORDER by import_added ASC 
LIMIT 0,100
```

When I use DESCRIBE to take a closer look at the query, my local machine uses the "added" index and returns 100 rows within a few milliseconds like expected.

When I use the same database with the same structure and content on my "production" server and use DESCRIBE there, it shows that the index is used as well, but it returns all rows in that table and the query takes about 6 seconds.

What am I missing? Why is the index not working correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Wrong usage of index

```
...
KEY `import_added` (import_completed, import_added) ...
```

And do a query execution plan

```
desc extended SELECT 
  import_id, 
  import_title, 
  import_url, 
  import_description, 
  import_user, 
  import_added 
FROM import 
WHERE import_completed = 'n' 
ORDER by import_added ASC 
LIMIT 0,100;
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thanks a lot! I must say I feel pretty stupid right now :)

Comment: @Bastian - more mistake you make, more experience you gained

Comment: Your localmachine probably used the old import_added key because there were few rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make an index on  `(import_completed, import_added)` The where part will use import_completed and for order by it will use import_added. (I hope this works on MyIsam - On Innodb this is the behavior)